# mysql - is it possible to create a partition expression based on two keys / indexes?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, partitioning, database-partitioning

if i have a table with, lets say 500 million rows, and among others there are two main individual indexes on that table. the table looks like:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `t1` (
>     id_1 bigint unsigned not null,
>     id_2 bigint unsigned not null,
>     col3, col4 ... colN ...
>     KEY `index1` (`id_1`),
>     KEY `index2` (`id_2`),
>     ...
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
> ```

100% of the queries on the table are using **WHERE** clause on index1 OR index2.

Taking this into account, and assuming it is now very reasonable time to partition that table, into 100 partitions, I just need to understand these two issues:

1. Is it possible to create a partition expression in such a way that after the partitioning, for any query that using one of these indexes:

   > ```
   > SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE id_1 = 123;
   > -- or
   > SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE id_2 = 456;
   > ```

   the engine will scan one partition only?
2. issue 1 must happen without changing the indexes. I mean, **without** making back references in them, because it will be too much RAM consuming. So, this must not happen:

   > ```
   > KEY `index1` (`id_1`,`id_2`),
   > KEY `index1` (`id_2`,`id_1`),
   > ```

HOW TO ? ANYONE?

EDIT

It was answered on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73734/mysql-is-it-possible-to-create-a-partition-expression-based-on-two-keys-inde), so I'll keep a reference here if anyone interested.

Answer (score 0):

You are barking up multiple wrong trees.

"Using where" is not evil.  `KEY(id_1)` and `WHERE id_1=123` performs as follows:

1. (very fast) Find the first id_1=123 in that index (which is structured as a BTree).
2. (proportional to number of 123's) Linearly scan through the index.
3. (also proportional, but slower) Reach for the row in question.

No form of partitioning is likely to speed that up any.

KEY `index1` (`id_1`,`id_2`) does not "live in RAM".  It ia "cached in RAM" as needed.  Yes, that is a little bigger than KEY(id_1), but not enough to worry about.  If you every need `WHERE id_1=123 AND id_2=456`, that composite index will be a lot faster.

Is (id_1, id_2) unique?  If so, and you do not have a `PRIMARY KEY` now, then this would be optimal:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id_1, id_2),
INDEX(id_1)
```

without any partitioning.  The PK would work very efficiently for `WHERE id_1=123`.  The INDEX would work adequately for `WHERE id_2=456`.